# Throw exception if bean is defined twice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

In my project I have different services. Each service can define its own `Permission`s. For each permission, a bean will created. This way, the `Authorization` service can inject all available permission, without actually knowing them.

The `Permission` definition of `ServiceA` will look like this:

```
@Configuration()
public class ServiceAPermissions extends Permissions {

    private static final String BASE = "servicea";
    public static final String SERVICEA_READ = join(BASE, READ);
    public static final String SERVICEA_WRITE = join(BASE, WRITE);

    @Bean()
    Permission getReadPermission() {
    return new Permission(SERVICEA_READ);
    }

    @Bean()
    Permission getWritePermission() {
    return new Permission(SERVICEA_WRITE);
    }
}
```

`ServiceB` will define the following `Permission`s:

```
@Configuration()
public class ServiceBPermissions extends Permissions {

    private static final String BASE = "serviceb";
    public static final String SERVICEB_READ = join(BASE, READ);

    @Bean()
    Permission getReadPermission() {
    return new Permission(SERVICEB_READ);
    }
}
```

Obviously, this will end in a name clash of the defined beans as I have defined a bean with the name `getReadPermission` twice. If course I can name the methods like `getServiceAReadPermission` so they will be distinguished, but this only a convention, which might be ignored.

In this situation, Spring doesn't notify me about the duplicate definition, it simply will just instantiate one and ignore the other definition. Is there a way to tell Spring to throw an `Exception`, if a bean is defined twice? This way one would be always aware of a duplicate definition.

Alternatively, is there a way to tell spring, that it should use a random bean name instead of the method signature? I know that I can give each bean a name manually `@Bean(name = "A name")`, but I like to avoid that, as a dev will not be forced to do so and still might forget it.

Comment: Probably you may implement the required verification by registering a BeanPostProcessor which would throw an exception in case of duplicate beans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That design does not seem very logical. A bean is supposed to be available only once, you're using it differently.

I'd suggest to provide a PermissionFactory-Bean which does what you need, along the line of

```
@Component
public class PermissionFactory {
    public Permission createFactory() {
        // create A or B permission randomly, as you wanted
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I did go for a factory which is registering beans. It works perfect and I can react to a already existing permission bean.